# C++, using initializers but for functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, initializer-list, initializer

Look at the first class :

```
     class A

{
    public:
        int x;
        A(int v) { x=v; }
};
```

Also, take a look at class B ( i used inheritance )

```
class B : public A //Inheritance{
public:
    B(int v) :A(v) {y=v; }
    int y;
};
```

Now can you explain why we use `:A (v)`?, i know that the initializer list can be used to initialize member variables, but... constructors ?! .
i think there's something about the initializer that i don't know, can you give me a good place to read about it ?

Comment: Please, format your text properly. Try to copy the formatting from all the C++ books you have read.

Comment: Also, where does the `v2` in `y=v2;` in the child class come from?

Comment: With what argument, the `Parent` constructor needs to be invoked, if you don't specify it? Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The compilation error is due to the absence of a integer-parametered constructor. When you do `Child c(10);` there should be a constructor that matches the arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 3):

> Now can you explain why we use Child(int v):Parent (v)

Because that is how you initialize the superclass in C++ when it only has such a constructor.

> When I delete it the program gives me a compilation error

Because you would then be implicitly calling the constructor `Parent()`, with no arguments, which doesn't exist, as your unstated compilation error undoubtedly states.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is *ill-formed*.

As per [class.ctor/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#8):

> A program is ill-formed if the *default constructor* for an object is
>   implicitly used and the `constructor` is *not* accessible

The moment you defined `Parent(int)` your implicitly-defined default constructor, `Parent()`, is *deleted*.

Thus, you need to *explicitly* call your *user-defined* constructor.

```
Child(int v):Parent (v) { }
```